# How to log backend latency in Google Http Load Balancer and Stack Driver

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, google-stackdriver

We have a running kubernetes cluster on GKE and we Google HTTP Load Balancer in front of it.

HTTP Load Balancer logs all requests and we can access them in stack driver logging. But latency is not logged, and I couldn't find a configuration for this. I want to get latency information for individual requests.

There are some latency reports in stack driver, so it should be logging in somewhere. Is it possible to access this information?

Comment: In web and application servers the log events will typically contain a field with the total time it took to serve/process a request, so are you looking for the right term?

Comment: It would be valuable if Google HTTP Load Balancers were logging the duration of HTTP transactions *from the balancer's perspective* -- from the beginning of the client's request (or perhaps the connection, if it's the first request) until the GFE has returned the last byte of the response to the client.  But this timing doesn't appear to be captured, and it isn't possible to learn this from the backend alone, since the RTT from GFE to backend is invisible to the backend, but potentially large -- and (I'm beginning to suspect) prone to substantial jitter, even on requests from the same client.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to view your latency by using [analysis reports](https://cloud.google.com/trace/docs/analysis-reports). Although it is using Stackdriver Trace, this may be a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @hachemon's answer, if you need a custom solution and the standar out-of-the-box Stackdriver Trace does not work for you, you can create your own custom solution and add it to your code using the [Stackdriver Trace API](https://cloud.google.com/trace/docs/reference/v2/rest/).